# Windows partition boots, but "The User Profile Service service failed the sign-in."

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, user-profiles, user-folders

I have a computer running Linux, with a second partition with Windows 10 for when I can't avoid it. Having not used that in months, I paid no mind when I got a new hard drive and used the opportunity to reorganize. Previously, both OSs shared the user-documents directories and suchlike, on a third partition. Now, those are structured in a way more convenient to the Linux side, and on a filesystem Windows can't read.

Months later, I needed Windows and this became a problem. I can boot Windows, but when I log in I get an error ("The User Profile Service service failed the sign-in. User profile cannot be loaded."). Can this be fixed by changing files from outside Windows, or do I need to reinstall?

Comment: enter Windows Safe Mode while the OS is loading with F8 key, enter a command prompt and run `sfc /scannow` just for making sure you don't have missing files, when the command ends, check the output and you will know if you have to reinstall.

Comment: Pressing F8 repeatedly, starting immediately after I selected Windows in GRUB does not lead to safe mode. I have transcribed the error message into the OP.

Comment: Boot up a Windows bootable media, load the SYSTEM registry hive with cmd, see if this registry `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ProfSvc` has **Start** registry set to **2** (i.e. Automatic) value.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Specifically, how to load a registry have with cmd. Google has not helped. I have got a command prompt open by shift-restart on the login screen.