# How can I reclaim partitions from unused dual-boot, without breaking existing OS on same drive?

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, multi-boot, grub

I run Linux Mint at the moment; at one point I dual-booted Windows but [I broke that by mistake about a year ago](https://superuser.com/questions/1250825/windows-partition-boots-but-the-user-profile-service-service-failed-the-sign-i), wasn't able to fix it (even reinstalling from disc failed, I think it was something about the drive's partitioning having been set up for GRUB?), and I have since found that I don't especially care. I would like to reclaim the space once devoted to that dual-boot, but I don't want to break the OS I actually use in the process.

My current boot drive is 256G, partitioned by MBR, with the following partitions (as displayed in the "Disks" GUI utility, left-to-right):

- `/dev/nvme0n1p1`: 524M, HPFS/NTFS bootable
- `/dev/nvme0n1p2`: 86G, HPFS/NTFS
- `/dev/nvme0n1`: 42G, unallocated (I wasn't sure initially whether I might want more space for one OS or the other, so I left a chunk open between them for expansion)
- `/dev/nvme0n1p3`: 108G, Extended

  - `/dev/nvme0n1p5`: 108G, Linux, Ext4 1.0, mounted at filesystem root.
- `/dev/nvme0n1`: 20G, unallocated (Not sure why I left this open. Something about performance issues with fully-allocated SSDs? Don't remember.)

I want to be very sure I don't break my OS in changing the partitions, but I do want to reclaim what I can of the more than half my drive currently going completely unused. How would this best be done?

Relatedly, I'm not sure whether there's any benefit in maintaining GRUB when there's no dual-booting to be done. On the other hand, it's small enough to be easily missed. I'm pretty sure the first (524M) partition is the GRUB one; do I keep it or wipe it?

I do have plenty of flash drives and an optical, so if booting from something else to make the change is necessary, I can do that.

GParted screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grub is still required to boot Mint. You may or may not see a menu at startup (not needed if there's only one OS).

You can reclaim the unused space without breaking the boot. If you instead kept Windows then you would need to reinstall the Windows bootloader instead of Grub but removing Windows and keeping Linux needs no additional user actions except maybe run `sudo update-grub` to get rid of the Windows boot entry.

(EDIT)
Screenshot provided so here are the specifics for this case:
The first two primary partitions - `nvme0n1p1` and `nvme0n1p2` (NTFS) - belong to Windows. Linux is on `nvme0n1p5`, a logical partition inside the extended primary `nvme0n1p3`. And there's unused/unallocated space between primary partitions and inside the extended one.

Let's deal with the latter first because reclaiming this space is independent of other actions and regardless of keeping Windows or not. Simply select `nvme0n1p3` (extended partition), right-click > resize and move the slider all the way to the right so it uses those 18.63GiB at the end of the drive. Repeat for `nvme0n1p5`, the logical partition inside. Click apply.

Now, decisions about what to do with the NTFS partitions. Surely they can both be deleted, the extended partition along with its contents moved all the way to the left, and all the remaining unused space reclaimed by repeating the above procedure.

My suggestion, for the sake of simplification, is to keep it as is and use as a data partition to save stuff. Simply forget about `nvme0n1p1` - 500MiB is a negligible loss - and resize (grow) `nvme0n1p2` to use all the remaining 38.70GiB with the same procedure as described above. Then delete all the contents (Windows folders and files).

Please note risk increases with the complexity of operations, growing a partition being the safest and moving (to the left) the least safe. Also, you need a live USB for this because when running your installed Linux Mint its partitions will be in use and can't be managed (unmounted partitions *can* be managed with GParted from within your Linux session). Any Linux distro with live media (and GParted) can be used, it doesn't have to match your installed OS. All Debian/Ubuntu and derivatives have live bootable media and GParted already installed in the live session.

Comment: So how, precisely, do I do the reclaiming? I want to be as safe as possible about this, and that means knowing what to do a lot better than I currently do, which means asking.

Comment: Managing partition is always risky but using the correct tools drastically reduces that risk. GParted in Linux is very easy to use. We may give a more detailed and tailored answer if you provide a screenshot of GParted showing your partitions layout.

Comment: GParted screenshot added to question.

Comment: Thank you. Specific details and comments added to the answer. Please comment if you need clarification and keep in mind the decision about what to do with the Windows partitions is entirely up to you.